# Send values for Servlet via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, dictionary

good night.

Personally, I have a function that simulates a "Map", where do I add as "Key" menu item and as "Values" menu subitems.

This function can be viewed below

```
var key;
var value;
var mapaDeListas = new Array();
$(".conteudoMenu a").click(function(){
   key = $(this).parent(".conteudoMenu").parent("li").find(".itemMenu").attr("id");
   value = $(this).attr("id"); 
   Processar();
   console.log(mapaDeListas);
});

var Processar = function() {
    if (mapaDeListas[key] && $.inArray(value, mapaDeListas[key]) == -1 || mapaDeListas[key] && $.inArray(value, mapaDeListas[key]) != -1) {
        // Checks if the key already exists from the "key" and if the value of "value" is present in the array
       if (mapaDeListas[key].indexOf(value) == -1){
            mapaDeListas[key].push(value);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Creates the array according to the value of the "key" and adds the value of "value"
        mapaDeListas[key] = new Array();
        mapaDeListas[key].push(value);
    }
}
```

What I would like to know was how do I pass the values of this function in Ajax to a Servlet and through them to assemble a Map  in java.

I tried to send the values of this function via Ajax as follows below, but to no avail

```
function loadQuery(){
    if(inputMenu.length > 0){
    $.ajax({
        url: "assembles-query",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "mapaDeListas[]" : mapaDeListas
        },
        //dataType: "json",
        error:function(){
            alert("ERRO MENU")
        },
        success:function(responseText){
            $("textarea[id=assembleQuery]").text(responseText);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

In the Servlet, tried to get the result as follows **String[] mapaDeListas = request.getParameterValues("mapaDeListas[]");**

However when I send print the result is always returned **null**.

Would someone please tell me where I am wrong and what should I do to pass these values correctly?
Since already thank you for everyone's help.

**Below has a print of how the result will be stored.**
http://bit.ly/V9oHsg

Comment: I'm not sure this `"mapaDeListas[]" : mapaDeListas` will wok. May be you should try to build yourself your GET URL (`url: "assembles-query",`) and append each element of your array

Comment: When I try to print just the mapaDeListas inside my loadQuery function () {} nothing is returned. It is as if the values were not being stored in the mapaDeListas. As that would be this suggestion that you spoke?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is with jQuery 1.4 - then  use the `traditional: true` parameter for [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)

Or  set it globally: ([from `$.param()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/))

> As of jQuery 1.4, the `$.param()` method serializes deep objects recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality globally by setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`.

Comment: Hello Sudhakar. As this could help me in the problem I am having? Thank you.